# Error after form resetting vee validate 3

Tags: vue.js, vee-validate

I am using vee-validate 3.1.1 and vue 2.5.17.

After successful form submission I am resetting the input

```
this.name = ''
```

But validation error message shows after resetting the input like the below image

[image]

There was same problem in vee-validate 2.*
I had solved that with this code

```
this.$nextTick(() => {
    this.errors.clear();
})
```

Answer (score 5):

```
//first reset your form values
this.name = '';
//then do this to reset your ValidationObserver
this.$nextTick(() => this.$refs.observer.reset());
```

This requires that you have your form inputs wrapped in a ValidationObserver with the attribute `ref="observer"`.  Otherwise, you'd want to call the `reset` method of each ValidationProvider you use, inside that same callback.

See [here](https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/guide/forms.html#resetting-forms) for the examples they give for vee-validate.  The "Resetting Forms" covers what you are doing, and the next example shows what I'm talking about ("Programmatic Access with $refs").

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. It didn't work for me if I reset form values at first. But after I reset validationObserver then form values it did work for me

Comment: I have a very similar problem like you, but this solution doesn't work for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59380609/validation-reset-after-form-submission

Answer (score 4):

Following the Vee-validate 3 [documentations](http://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v2/guide/components/validation-observer.html#examples) it is recommended to reset the form after the animation frames are requested.

You could do something like this:

```
methods: {
    async reset() {
       this.name = '';
       requestAnimationFrame(() => {
          this.$refs.observer.reset();
       );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is known to be a bug with VeeValidate, and for some reason it hasn't been taken care of, but making `async` method to first reset the variable, and next the observer, seems to make it working.

So you could stick to this work-around, until VeeValidate fix it some day.

```
methods: {
  async resetForm() {
    this.name = '';
    this.$refs.observer.reset();
  }
}
```