# Validation reset after form submission

Tags: validation, vue.js, vee-validate

I've got the form with checkboxes and I want the user to select at least one of them. Everything works fine, but after resetting the form I can't hide the validation message.
This case is described exactly in the [docs](https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/guide/forms.html#programmatic-access-with-refs), but the provided solution seems to be invalid because after submitting the form validation errors show up.

```html
    <template>
      <v-app>
        <v-content>
          <playground></playground>
          <v-card class="mx-auto" outlined>
            <ValidationObserver ref="obs" v-slot="{ invalid, valid, validated, passes, reset }">
              <v-card-title class="pb-0">Meal types</v-card-title>
              <v-row justify="center">
                <v-col cols="11">
                  <v-form ref="form">
                    <ValidationProvider rules="required" v-slot="{ errors, failedRules }">
                      <v-container row pa-0>
                        <v-row justify="space-around">
                          <v-checkbox
                            v-model="mealType"
                            value="BREAKFAST"
                            label="Breakfast"
                            hide-details
                          ></v-checkbox>
                          <v-checkbox v-model="mealType" value="DINNER" label="Dinner" hide-details></v-checkbox>
                          <v-checkbox v-model="mealType" value="SUPPER" label="Supper" hide-details></v-checkbox>
                          <v-checkbox v-model="mealType" value="SNACK" label="Snack" hide-details></v-checkbox>
                        </v-row>
                      </v-container>
                      <v-row justify="center">
                        <v-alert
                          v-if="failedRules.required"
                          type="error"
                          dense
                          outlined
                          class="mt-4 mb-0"
                        >Select at least one meal type</v-alert>
                      </v-row>
                    </ValidationProvider>
                  </v-form>
                </v-col>
              </v-row>
              <v-card-actions>
                <v-row justify="center">
                  <v-btn text color="deep-purple accent-4" @click="passes(addRecipe)">Save</v-btn>
                  <v-btn @click="reset">Reset</v-btn>              
                </v-row>
              </v-card-actions>
            </ValidationObserver>
          </v-card>
        </v-content>
      </v-app>
    </template>

    <script>
    import Playground from "./components/Playground";

    export default {
      name: "App",
      components: {
        Playground
      },
      data() {
        return {
          recipeName: "",
          mealType: []
        };
      },
      methods: {
        addRecipe() {
          console.log("add recipe");
          // after save or reset alerts should disappear..
          this.$refs.form.reset();
          requestAnimationFrame(() => {
            this.$refs.obs.reset();
          });
        }
      }
    };
    </script>
```

Code Sandbox with reproduced use case: https://codesandbox.io/s/vee-validate-3-reset-checkbox-validation-qr8uw
Please select some meal types and click save. After clicking the save button, the form is reset and the validation message shows up, but it shouldn't. How to solve this?

Comment: Seems like a bug, you should report it here:  https://github.com/logaretm/vee-validate/issues

Comment: `failedRules` is not reset, but `errors` is, which is what the docs use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a workaround, which will help you solving the issue (the original with `this.$refs.form.reset()`), has to be a bug, and should be reported to VeeValidate for solving.

I found out making the method `async`, and resetting the variable manually made it all work out.

```
methods: {
  async addRecipe() {
    console.log("add recipe");
    console.log(this.mealType);

    this.mealType = [];
    this.$refs.obs.reset();
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm still not sure that there is a bug with `failedRules`, but your solution seems to work fine, thanks!.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work as expected. The form seems to be reset before submission and returns empty values. Please see https://codesandbox.io/s/vee-validate-3-reset-checkbox-validation-irqpg

Comment: @kojot New solution added

Comment: this doesnt work for me unfortunately.